# Clear fields that have been hidden

Tags: angularjs

I have this form.

When the user checks a check box, some fields get hidden, others appear.

What is the correct way to clear the fields that have been hidden?

Use a watch?

Answer (score 0):

On the click event of your checkbox clear all the fields that it controls.